# How to render geometric normals?

Tags: scripting, normals, normal-map, render-layers, compositing-nodes

When we import a mesh into Blender, we can get a lot of information, and `normal` is one of the properties.

The `Normal` in `Render Layers` in the `Compositing` is connected to `File Output`, and export in `exr` format:

[image]

We then form a point cloud with normal (without faces). The result is:

[image]

and the correct normal should be:

[image]

And we also found that the length of the `normal` is not equal to one, so how to render the numerically accurate `normal`, and what's the meaning of the `Normal` in `Render Layers`? In addition, what is the difference between normals obtained in "Shading" and "Compositing"?

[Here](https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/b7bb7da0-2b07-11ec-995f-d5fbedf0f746) we provide data and code for the test:

- step 1: /home/lab9/Installs/blender-2.92.0-linux64/blender --background --python /home/lab9/Documents/blender_render/blender_0_render.py -- 0 1 1 "test"
- step 2: python blender_2_postprocess.py
- step 3: python test.py

Please pay attention to modify the `path_pfx` in the file.

And the colored point cloud is (the rightmost is correct):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following three settings, please point out any errors:

1. Normal(World Space) in [Geometry Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html)

[image]

2. Normal(Object Space) in [Texture Coordinate Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html)

[image]

3. You can convert to Camera Space by

[image]